# Ingress paths not matching with Minikube Nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm attempting to set up an Nginx Ingress on my local Minikube, but am having problems with the paths actually matching. I have two services set up, that I want to each serve different paths at the same domain. One is a Django-based API backend, the other is a Node-based frontend. My Ingress configuration is as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 3000
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: backend
          servicePort: 8000
      - path: /admin
        backend:
          serviceName: backend
          servicePort: 8000
      - path: /static
        backend:
          serviceName: backend
          servicePort: 8000
```

If I navigate to `http://test.local/` in my browser, the Node frontend successfully serves that route. If I navigate to `http://test.local/admin/`, the Django backend successfully serves that route, and corrects redirects to `http://pingpong.local/admin/login/?next=/admin/` since I am not logged in (which is also served correctly from the Django backend). However, none of the CSS loads, because `http://test.local/static/` is being served by the Node frontend for some reason. Everything under the `/api` route also gets served by the Node frontend.

None of the documentation, examples, or other resources that I've been able to find seem to indicate that I'm doing anything incorrectly here, so I'm at a bit of a loss to figure out why it's *sort of* working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm still not sure exactly what the problem was, but after a restart of my computer, the Ingress is now working as I'd expect it to… Current best guess is some sort of caching happening somewhere.